# Taking a specific range of data in a CSV file (Python)

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Basically, what I want to do here is read in a specific range of data (Say, 10,000 values) and see if it contains a match that I'm looking for. If it doesn't contain that match, then it throws out those values and takes the next 10,000.

For example, if I have the MD5 hash "fac2a47adace059aff113283a03f6760" (The value of which is stack), I will load 10,000 values from a CSV file and check to see if the MD5 hash in that line matches up with my given hash. If it does, then I print out the value after the comma on that line, and if it doesn't then throw those 10,000 values out of memory and take the 10,000 after that until I get a value.

Apologies of this is a bit unclear... I can't think of a crystal-clear way of explaining it. My current method of doing things is dumping a dictionary containing all the combinations of characters (up to 5) to a text file via JSON and loading that back into memory to be searched, which doesn't work with 5 characters (Throws a MemoryError).

Thanks in advance for any help, and let me know if you need clarification!

Comment: Can't you just iterate over the rows until you find the one that matches?

Comment: If it loads the entire file into memory, then definitely not. Because that's the issue here: Not having enough RAM to get the entire file in.

Comment: The `csv` module doesn't.

Comment: The `csv` module is lazy, so this is trivial, as others have said. Just use a `for` loop over a `csv.reader()`, and you are golden.

Comment: Much simpler than I expected, then. Cheers! How would I get the decrypted value after I've found the matching hash, however?

Comment: If the file is line based (one line per value of interest) the file object is already a generator and you could just iterate without using `csv`. You'd need to split it yourself though.

Comment: @dantdj - you cannot (at least trivially) find the unencrypted value of an MD5 hash. MD5 is supposed to be a one-way hash function. Are you trying to go through password dictionaries? [Rainbow tables](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) might be helpful

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee - This isn't really intended to be something that's used seriously, more just me exploring a bit of hashing and file generation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the matching line looks like 'fac2a47adace059aff113283a03f6760,stack', you basically want to do this:

```
for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
    if row[0] == "fac2a47adace059aff113283a03f6760":
        print row[1]
        break
```

If your hash isn't in the first column or your pre-hash value isn't in the second, adjust the [0] and [1] to the right indexes.